# String contain string

Tags: objective-c

after a decent search and could not find solution (probably i missed something...):

i have an array with objects, the object is `AddressCard` and one if the properties is `name`.

so i send to my function string and with for statement looking all the matches inside my object collection array who contain AddressCArd object (bookArray) and if there is match i want to add this object to an array asnd return this array:

```
-(NSMutableArray *) lookup:(NSString *) name
{
    NSMutableArray arr = [NSMutableArray array];

    for(AddressCard *card in bookArray}
    {
        if([card.name rangeOfString: name].location == NSNotfound)
        {
             [arr addObject: card];
        }  
    }

    return arr;
}
```

Comment: You did `== NSNotFound` which adds to the array if there is no match. You probably meant `!= NSNotFound`.

Comment: What the heck, typos are filled here and there, syntax errorsssss!!!!

Comment: @user2214609: Whats the error or output?

Comment: no error cause the array is ampty, no results found, for example in my objects array i have the name: @"Carl ror" so i want to find all the matches with the string car

Comment: NSMutableArray arr = [NSMutableArray array]; replace with NSMutableArray arr = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init]; and try

Comment: The string "Carl ror" doesn't contain the string "car". You need to do a case insensitive compare.

Comment: whats NSMutableArray arr = [NSMutableArray array]; ?

Comment: @user2214609: that is why you are struggling hard. You need to explain all the requirement at first then only look for the answers/solutions. Check my answer and tell if this works or nt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do as this:

```
-(NSMutableArray *) lookup:(NSString *) name {
    NSMutableArray *arr = [NSMutableArray array];
    for(AddressCard *card in bookArray) {
        //if([card.name isEqualToString:name]) {
        if([[card.name capitalizedString] rangeOfString:[name capitalizedString]].location != NSNotFound)
             [arr addObject:card];
        }  
    }
    return arr;
}
```